# How to stop concurrent ajax calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to cancel a jquery.load()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813168/how-to-cancel-a-jquery-load)

Ok so I have an autocomplete field that is making an ajax request every keystroke....which can slow things down alot. If you visit [here](http://doorsplit.heroku.com/) and use the

email: test@test.com
pass:  test12

If you have firebug open and start typing fast you will see all the see all the ajax requests. My question is can i cancel the previous request if there is a more recent one. here is my code.

This is my autocomplete call using this [plugin](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#installation)

```
$('#request_artist').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: '<%= ajax_path("artistName") %>',
  minChars:1,
  width: 300,
  delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
  deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
  params: { artists: 'Yes' },
});
```

From there I call the ajax from my rails application using

from my rails action I make a call to the itunes api

http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=metalicca

really my question is, Is there a way to tell if an ajax is running and kill it

Comment: See a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813168

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the [AJAX Queue/Cache/Abort/Block Manager](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/), it was what I used when I had a similar problem. Using the `abortOld` option, the plugin will abort old requests when responses to newer requests come in.