# Stop a jQuery load() event for iframe

Tags: ajax, jquery, load, jquery-load

I'm using the jQuery load() event to load a page into an iframe. The page that is being loaded contains a script which access two API's and therefore take some time to load (~15-30 seconds). I want to add a button/link to the loading screen that you can click to cancel the load, otherwise you are unable to navigate away from the page. Currently, I have:

```
<script>
function callIframe(url) {
    $('#analyticsloader').show();
    $('#analytics').html('<iframe src="" allowtransparency="yes" style="width:735px;height:1510px;border:0;" id="analyticsiframe"></iframe>');
    $('iframe#analyticsiframe').attr('src', url);
    $('iframe#analyticsiframe').load(function(){
        $('#analyticsloader').hide();
    });
}
$(function(){
    callIframe('analytics/index.php');
    var start, end;
    $('#updateStats').click(function(){
        start = $('#startDate').val();
        end = $('#endDate').val();
        callIframe('analytics/index.php?start='+start+'&end='+end);
    });
});
</script>
```

`#analyticsloader` is a div with an ajax loader graphic and "Please wait while I load blah blah", I would like to add a Cancel button into it that would stop the load() function from executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to your question might be here:

[How to cancel a jquery.load()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813168/how-to-cancel-a-jquery-load)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.abort-ajax').click(function(){
     x.abort();
});
```

where "x" is a variable where you save the ajax request.

or this [jquery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/AjaxQueue).