# .load() multiple link addresses into one div

Tags: jquery, function, live

I have a really long block of code below, I am loading text into a div while hovering over another div, I want to load a bunch of different links into the same div, I have two problems

1) I know there is a better way to write this code, using an array - I need to learn how to write arrays.

2) I need the animations to stop if the mouse is moving fast, and not keep loading the #id's for a long time if you scribble your mouse over all the links

does that make sense??

```
$(function() {
$(".cell_1 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #arkitek_reel');
    });
$(".cell_1 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_2 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ab_sciex');
    });
$(".cell_2 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_3 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #stratos_');
    });
$(".cell_3 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_4 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #riken_');
    });
$(".cell_4 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_5 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #scitable_');
    });
$(".cell_5 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_6 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ubc_asthma');
    });
$(".cell_6 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_7 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #xcelligence_');
    });
$(".cell_7 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_8 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #lbsc_geneware');
    });
$(".cell_8 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_9 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #nr_micro');
    });
$(".cell_9 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_10 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #genII_knee');
    });
$(".cell_10 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_11 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #exiqon_');
    });
$(".cell_11 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_12 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #hpi_');
    });
$(".cell_12 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_13 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #plexmark_');
    });
$(".cell_13 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_14 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #siscapa_');
    });
$(".cell_14 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_15 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #RNAi_');
    });
$(".cell_15 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_16 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #k2_');
    });
$(".cell_16 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_17 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #nucleonics_');
    });
$(".cell_17 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_18 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ca125_');
    });
$(".cell_18 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_19 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #cci_nursing');
    });
$(".cell_19 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_20 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #cadherins_');
    });
$(".cell_20 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".cell_21 a").live('mouseover', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load('http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ascent_');
    });
$(".cell_21 a").live('mouseout', function(){
    $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid code repetition, i'd do this:

```
var urls = [
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #cadherins_',
 'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ascent_',
 ...
];

$(document).ready(function() {    
    for(var i=0; i< urls.length; i++){
        $(".cell_"+(i+1)+" a").hover(function(){
            $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load(urls[i]);
        }, function(){
            $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Behold.

```
$(function() {
    var urls = [
        'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #cadherins_',
        'http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/includes/work-info.inc #ascent_',
        ..etc..
    ];
    for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
        var index = i+1;
        $(".cell_"+index+" a").live('mouseover', function(){
            $('#gridInfo').fadeIn(100).load(urls[i]);
        });
        $(".cell_"+index+" a").live('mouseout', function(){
            $('#gridInfo').fadeOut(100);
        });
    }
});
```

for the loading thing see here [How to cancel a jquery.load()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813168/how-to-cancel-a-jquery-load)

Comment: watch out, mouseover will trigger hundreds of events! (so maaany ajax calls!)

Comment: not getting a result yet here.. thank you so much for your help in advance!! This is a big step for me to learn and will help me ttons

Comment: I can see the code is effecting my gridInfo div but is failing to actually load the content

Comment: try it as 2 lines. seperate the fadein and the load

Comment: still nothing, the opacity of my div is cranking on and off, but no 'load'

Comment: ok turn off the opacity change. this will help you isolate the bug. going to the urls in the example i get a 404. are they correct

Comment: its just a page with a unordered list and the id tags point to different anchors

Comment: that link is different to the ones you provided. also you have a space before the # in the original links