# jQuery load loads previous page if a is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, load

I have this issue with jQuery `.load()`:

I have a test page called a.php and in there is:

```
sleep(5);
```

So that sleeps for 5 seconds. In my jQuery if that page has started to load and you click another link, it loads that page and then shortly after it loads the previous page.

Is there anyway to stop this?

Code is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$("#load").hide(); //Hife the loading bar


$("a").click(function(){ //On click
    if(!$(this).hasClass('ignoreJS'))
    {
        $("#load").show();

        $("#mainContent").hide();

        addActive( this );

        var FullAttribute = $(this).attr('href');
        var FinalAttribute = FullAttribute.slice(1);

        $('#mainContent').load( FinalAttribute + '.php', function(response, status, xhr)
        {
            if(status)
            {
                if(status == 'error' && xhr.status != 0)
                {
                    $('#mainContent').html('<h2 class="errorText">Error ' + xhr.status + ' </h2>');
                }
                waitingToLoad = false;

            }
            $("#mainContent").show();
            $("#load").hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel a jquery.load()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813168/how-to-cancel-a-jquery-load)

Comment: @hexblot I am looking for a solution to my problem, not an alternative

Comment: it's not an alternative, it is a question about stopping http requests generated by jquery.load , same as you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("a").click(function(){ //On click

  // <your original code>

  // add this at the end of your function
  return false;

});
```

The `return false` statement will prevent the browser to follow the `href` address of your `a` tag.

Comment: No that wouldn't work, it needs to somehow stop the http request i believe, however outside of the load, inside it didn't work using xhr.abort()