# JQuery cancel .load event

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible in JQuery to cancel a .load() before making any changes to the html element?

For instance:

```
$(".userElementsList").load("/userList/addNewUser",
    params,
    function (responseText, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        try {
            var response = $.parseJSON(responseText);
            alert(response.message);
            $(". userElementsList").off();
        } catch (error) {
            cleanningUserPopupData();
            $("#userPopup").modal("hide");
        }
    }
);
```

I have a page with a table and a popup that allows to create users, when the user clicks in create the code above is executed. If there isn't any errors it should return a html content to build the users table in the page, but in case of any error occurs it returns a json content with the error to show in the popup.

Comment: What is that try catch supposed to do? Do not use load, use Ajax method GET and set the HTML yourself. .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813168/how-to-cancel-a-jquery-load