# How to cancel an image from loading

Tags: javascript, tags, load, image

Suppose in Javascript that you assign the SRC to an IMG tag.  It is a large SRC and you want to cancel it before it has finished loading.  Assigning the SRC to another image will not stop the data from loading.

That is, in the middle of the load you can assign the SRC to another smaller image and the smaller image will be loaded and appear in your browser.  However, the original SRC still continues downloading.

Similarly, deleting the IMG node will not prevent the SRC from continuing to download.  No guesses please, look at the repro steps.

REPRO

1. Load this URL in Chrome in Windows:  http://68.178.240.17/imgLoadTest/imgLoadTest.htm
2. Open up the developer panel by pressing CTRL-SHIFT-J
3. On the top row of icons in the Chrome developer panel click the Network icon to watch network activity.
4. On the web page loaded in Step 1 click the Load Image button and watch the developer panel as a large (32meg) image starts loading.
5. On the web page click the Try To Cancel button to load a different image.
6. A small image loads, but watch the network in the developer panel and notice that the large image continues to download.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926215/cancel-single-image-request-in-html5-browsers

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Quick answer

Setting the `src` attribute of the `img` tag to an empty string will interrupt the current download, even on Chrome.

###Details
Nowadays *most of* browsers implemented that out-of-standard mechanism thought in the old answer to programmatically abort the connection. This is not achieved through a protocol request, but with a client-side in-memory operation. Keep in mind that is not a standard behaviour, but most of vendors courtesy. That is, it could not work on every browser.

I've prepared a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nw34gLgt/) showing this mechanism in action (keep an eye at the **network** panel of the inspector).

---

### Old answer (2011)

Your browser asks for that image with a specific HTTP GET request, as specified in HTTP protocol. Once it asks for it, the http server starts the transfer.

So, it is between the browser (as http client) and the http server.

Since http protocol does not take into account the option to abort a transfer, the browser should implement an out-of-standard mechanism to programmatically abort the connection. But since this is not specified in any standard, i think you won't find any way to do that with javascript or any client side code.

Comment: "*Since http protocol does not takes into account the option to abort a transfer,*"    -    But you can suspend or abort a file download (that is an HTTP GET request).

Comment: @Paolo I do not know where you got this information from, but no, you cannot suspend (HTTP is a stateless protocol) or abort any file download, even less with a GET request.

Comment: I understand your point. But actually you can start a download of a file (from the browser) and then at a certain point you can abort the download. I get this information *naively* from the browser's interface. What happens then? Isn't the transmission actually stopped? Or is it just the client that starts ignoring incoming data (while the server keeps sending) ?

Comment: @Paolo If you are referring to the "stop download" function of the browser, that's another story: that is the **browser application** closing the network socket (it does not send or use a HTTP GET request: it is done with Java, C++, or whatever programming language the browser is made of), where the transfer is running. You cannot close a socket with JavaScript, nor you can abort the transfer since the HTTP protocol does not take into account such a possibility.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now

Answer (score 5):

Cancel with transparent base64 encoded GIF to avoid additional requests and double page load on android:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://google.com/favicon.ico';

img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAI=;'
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I can't find the bug report now, I believe this is a long-standing logged WebKit bug. Firefox (and IE I think) have more sane behavior.  I'm going back a bit in my brain, but if I recall on those browsers, resetting the img.src will in fact cancel outstanding downloads.  I am positive that Firefox does this when a download is "waiting in line" for a chance at an open HTTP connection, and I seem to recall that it will actually force close connections sometimes.

I've never found a way to coax WebKit based browsers into cancelling an img download in progress, whether it is just queued or already actively downloading.

This really sucks if you're making something like a mapping client and need more fine grained control over images.

Comment: Have you found a workaround or webkit by any chance? Setting src to "" doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

Setting the .src property to an empty string should cancel the load:

```
//load image from url
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://somedomain.com/image.jpg';

......

//cancel load
img.src = '';
```

Comment: I search too a solution but set an empty string come with some effect has explain here :
https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, page is downloaded twice on Android when an img tag has an src="" attribute.
This still occurs on recent Android versions.
I have not found any other browser that does that.
But I found a solution: use an img tag without src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

the src property must be a [valid non-empty URL](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-img-src)
So null or empty string are not legal (even though they sometimes work).

Use:

```
img.src='http://xxxx';
img.onerror=null;
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17656617/460084))

Answer (score 0):

The ultimative answer is web workers.
Load the image inside an webworker and stopping the web worker will stop the image loading.

You can get the idea from this code:
https://github.com/NathanWalker/ng2-image-lazy-load

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
imageVarName.src = '';
imageVarName.onload = null;
imageVarName.onerror = null;
```

Comment: Please don't just give a block of code as an answer! You should explain why and how this works

Comment: This gets cast to a relative url of the index of your site (e.g. `http://example.com/`), which is probably not an image, and will skew the traffic stats of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, setting src to an empty string does not work in WebKit-based browsers like Safari. Here is the link to the bug report which Stella mentioned.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6656