# Why is Chrome's onerror event for the img element only fired once?

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, events, onerror

Why is Chrome is only calling the onerror event for the img element one time when all other browsers (IE7,8,9, FF, Opera, and Safari) all call it repeatedly?

Is there a way to force it to repeat the onerror call again (in Chrome)?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/ff8ph/7/)

***HTML:***

```
<div id="thisWorks">
    this works in Chrome. onerror event is called once.
    <img src="http://www.asdfjklasdfasdf.com/bogus1.png" 
        onerror="fixit(this);" 
        rsrc="http://eatfrenzy.com/images/success-tick.png" />
</div>

<div id="thisDoesNotWork">
    this does not work in Chrome. onerror event is not called twice.
    <img src="http://www.asdfjklasdfasdf.com/bogus1.png" 
        onerror="fixit(this);"
        rsrc="http://www.asdfjklasdfasdf.com/bogus2.png|http://eatfrenzy.com/images/success-tick.png" />
</div>
```

***JAVASCRIPT:***

```
function fixit(img)
{
    var arrPhotos = img.getAttribute('rsrc').split('|');

    // change the img src to the next available
    img.setAttribute('src', arrPhotos.shift());

    // now put back the image list (with one less) into the rsrc attr
    img.setAttribute('rsrc', arrPhotos.join('|'));

    return true;    
}
```

**EDIT:**
Per @Sunil D.'s comment about Chrome not issuing a new lookup due to invalid domain name of `www.asdfjklasdfasdf.com` in the [initial fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/ff8ph/3/) example, I went ahead and changed the domain name to match that of the success image, but with a different filename so it still is a 404. That will prove it's not the invalid domain name causing Chrome to bail out on the 2nd attempt.

**EDIT:**
Updated fiddle and removed use of jquery to simply things and rule that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay got it. Inside the function you assign to the onerror event, **set the `src` attribute to `null` before changing it to its new value**.

```
img.setAttribute('src', null);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/ff8ph/8/)


This somehow causes Chrome to reset it and will force it to repeatedly call onerror if subsequent values for `src` return an error.


**Note:** an empty string won't work and needs to be `null`.

**Note2:** this fix works using pure javascript (but not with the jquery `.attr` method). After I posted this solution I tried it with the jquery `.attr` method setting it to `$img.attr('src', null);` but it didn't work that way and when I changed it to javascript, it worked. I also tried it using the jquery `.prop` method instead like so `$img.prop('src', null);` which worked the first time and failed on a few subsequent refreshes. Only the pure javascript seems to be a surefire solution.

**UPDATE:**
Okay, turns out that while the above change fixes Chrome and causes it to repeatedly call onerror like all other other browsers (FF, Safari, Opera, IE7-9), it causes problems with the onerror event for IE10 and thus ignores any valid images assigned to `src` after setting it to `=null` on the previous line. (...sigh).

Comment: You can please **SOME** of the browsers **ALL** of the time, You can please **ALL** of the browsers **SOME** of the time, But you can't please **ALL** of the browsers **ALL** of the time.

Comment: the answer by Jess works in all browsers reliably (although his jsfiddle is broken), and is not even a hack - you should accept it instead of this one, as yours makes additional requests...

Answer (score 6):

I've tried the ways metioned above, setAttribute('src', null) has a side effect, ie, add another request.

Finally, I use

```
    setTimeout(function(){ imgElement.src = 'http://xxxx'; }, 0)
```

, and this works!

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32GE8/) for example.

Comment: just make jsFiddle run to noWrap instead of unload

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior. You don't want to download the same image twice -- that's a waste of bandwidth.

What Chrome does it create an in-memory object and then will apply it to all images with the respective `src`.

If you need it downloaded twice, then create those objects through javascript and assign `.onload=function() { .. }` to each.

Comment: it's not downloading anything twice. In the fiddle, when the initial image in the `src` attribute is not found, it fires the `onerror` event which changes the img element's `src` attribute to a new URL. When the new URL is re-evaluated and determined to be a 404 again, it should again call the `onerror` event until you derefernce it with `onerror = ''`. Just like all the other browsers do. Try the fiddle in Chrome and also in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Mikhail is on the right track, except for a slightly different reason. In the second example, you attempt to download 2 images from the same non-existent domain `www.asdfjklasdfasdf.com`.

When attempting to download `bogus1.png`, Chrome fails to resolve the domain to an IP address.

When attempting to download `bogus2.png` (from the same non-existent domain), Chrome doesn't do anything at all... because it knows the domain lookup has failed. Whether it's correct behavior for chrome not to dispatch another `onerror` event might be open to debate :) I sort of expect that it should.

To prove this, simply add 1 character to the domain name for `bogus2.png` and it will work as you expected.

**Edit**

One way you could force it to attempt the subsequent downloads is to change the `src` of the `<img>` to the empty string. It's kind of hacky, but it works. You could set your `rsrc` attribute to something like this:

```
rsrc="''|http://www.asdfjklasdfasdf.com/bogus2.png|''|http://eatfrenzy.com/images/success-tick.png"
```

This way, when the error occurs, you set the source to ''. This seems to generate an error too, which then triggers it to try the next source...

Comment: Blarg! I think my edit was erroneous. Your original example is working for me now, when it didn't earlier.

Comment: you're on to something by suggesting to set the `src` attribute to an empty string in between onerror calls. It seems to work in Chrome that way and continue to repeatedly call it, but not sure why.

Comment: interesting point about the domain, but that's not why it's bailing out. I changed the fiddle above to use the same domain name with just a bogus filename and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Etdashou on this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891041/1090274, setting `this.onerror=null;` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, keep switching alternate sources on each onerror, and if finally fails, clears the `onerror` to break to the loop. Works fine on `img`, `script` tags on multiple browses.

Js:

```
function alt_(elm, src_list, attr){
  /*elm: element
    src_list: list of links 
    attt: src*/
  if(src_list==[]){
    elm.onerror="";
    return false;
  }
  
  elm[attr]=src_list[0];
  // console.log(src_list[0])
  elm.onerror = function(){alt_(elm, src_list.slice(1), attr)};
}

const alt_logos = ['B1.jpg', 'B2.jpg', 'backupsite.com/B4.jpg']
```

HTML:

```
<img src="main.jpg" onerror="alt_(this, alt_logos, 'src')">
```

Works both chrome and FF.

**Update**: seems this won't work for link tags (href). Also, seems like script tag onerror fires only once.