# Swapping image when url returns 404 not working with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, fallback

I have the following function as a fallback when the URL of the image returns 404. The function should happen after the AJAX. So when AJAX is made, and the URL returns 404, the image will replace the broken image. This functions works in Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome.

When it's not working in Chrome, the console says:

> imageOnError is not defined.

```
    function imageOnError(img) {
       img.onerror = ' ';
       img.src = "http://v.images.boldride.com/vorsteiner/2012/vorsteiner-bmw-m3-gts5.1471x972.Jul-11-2012_13.02.33.232886.jpg";
       return true;
    }
```

Any ideas what's going on with it?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjx7fgxw/)

Comment: Post entire code, how you attach imageOnError function to the image object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17636872/2020002 have you checked that?

Comment: So this is angular? Where is `imageOnError` is defined, global function?

Comment: @dfsq why would this be angular? This looks like any code with mustache-style templating (could be plain mustache, nunjucks, angular, take your pick)

Comment: @dfsq, this isn't angular. It was handlebar.js was used to parse the image url. I've revised it to a broken image url.

Comment: well the fact that you are getting it intermittently means you are having a race issue where the image loads before javascript...where/how are you including the function?

Comment: @DavidNguyen, the function gets called when the url returns 404.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sjx7fgxw/1/

Answer (score 0):

When browser gets this:

```
<img src="http://ip.dlron.us/img.jpg"
     onerror="return imageOnError(this);">
```

the image's URL may already be tested against existence (and result cached) and so browser can tell right away that image is not available and call your onerror handler.

Thus your `imageOnError(img)` implementation shall appear in HTML before first image that uses it.

Comment: It seems to be the problem, but the page(image content) gets generated by both AJAX and HTML.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "page(image content)" and "image content gets generated by both AJAX and HTML" ?

Comment: I think the issue has something to do with the AJAX call, maybe because when AJAX renders the content, the `imageOnError function` wasn't ready or something.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jQuery to solve this problem. It actually works better than calling `onerror` event directly on markup. Thanks everyone's help.

```
$(errorImage).on('error', function(){
  $(this).attr('src', 'broken-image-url');
});
```