# jQuery run "onerror" function for img tag when manually setting its source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that is loading some public camera feeds from an API. Every few minutes, a timer will reset the `src` of each time with a new appended parameter so that the browser updates it without having to do a page reload.

Some of these images fail to load though due to them not being available, thus returning an error such as `404`. To fix this, I put in an `onerror` function that replaces the `src` of the image with a default one in the event it doesnt load, all is working good.

```
<img data-title="' + v.intersection + '" data-img="' + baseFeedURL + v.imageName + '?r=' + Date.now() + '" class="img-fluid loading camera" src="' + baseFeedURL + v.imageName + '?r=' + Date.now() + '" alt="' + v.intersection + ' Camera Down" onerror="this.onerror=null;noImage(this, '+ v.cameraID + ');">;
```

The `noImage` function just returns a new image `src`.

```
function noImage(image, cameraID){
    return $(image).attr('src', 'img/img_not_available.gif');
}
```

What I need to do though is be able to re-try these images and see if there is now a response on them. To prepare for this, I added `data-img` to each of the images which contains the original image url (since we modify the source on broken ones).

I then created a function that loops over all images that have that default `src` (the ones I am re-checking) and replace their `src` with the original one stored in `data-img`.

```
function recheckFeeds(){
    $("img[src$='img/img_not_available.gif']").each(function(){
       $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-img'));
    })
}
```

This happens correctly and I see it get updated in the DOM when I invoke the function.

The issue I am running into however is that the `onerror` function doesn't seem to be running again. When I try and re-set the src, some times the urls still don't work so I need the `onerror` to trigger again and set it back to the default image.

So, in short - I need to figure out how to run `onerror` on a an `img` when programmatically setting its source.

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17636872/1848744)? Long story short it seems to be Chrome-specific and the solution is to `set the src attribute to null before changing it to it's new value inside the function you assign to the onerror event`

Comment: @MattNewelski - Looks promising, will check it out now!

Comment: This may be an outdated answer, having trouble getting it to work

Comment: Can you confirm that this occurs on all browsers?

Comment: I just noticed the `this.onerror=null` part inside of onerror on the image element. Did you add that just recently?

Comment: @MattNewelski - No, I had that in there because many posts said if the replacement image also didn't exist, it would cause a loop.

Comment: What's the interval at which you run the recheckFeeds() and at how many retries should the script give up?

Comment: I run it every 30 seconds, nothing set in place to stop it. Every 30 seconds, replaces the src on images that received the default image from the first `onerror` call with its original url to see if the external image exists again. The `onerror` no longer fires and sets this back to the default image.

Comment: @MattNewelski Here is a fiddle of the basic issue I am facing. https://jsfiddle.net/s10pvezg/13/

Comment: I have identified the problem to in fact be strictly in the `this.onerror=null` assignment - the suggestion to include it in order to avoid loops was wrong because it assumed that you are calling your image recheck function from within the onerror handler rather than setting it up externally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the image encounters an error the first `this.onerror=null` assignment of your `onerror` attribute expression removes all further calls therefore after you replace it with the broken source again during recheck it will not fire, leaving the image blank.

Here is the way I would approach this problem that involves setting the recheck interval as well as the max times the recheck function should run before giving up (i.e. the image error is not intermittent).

Please note that in the image recheck I am using only `[data-src]` selector with the assumption that only images that called the error handler will have this attribute. If you want to ensure only images with currently broken image are targeted I would use a separate identifier of either a class or another data- attribute (i.e. `data-error=true` or `class=brokensrc`) and then remove said identifier once the src is confirmed to be valid.

```js
// interval is the amount of time in ms between rechecking the broken images
var interval = 3000;

// maxRetry is the max amount of times the images will be rechecked
var maxRetry = 5;

// thisRetry is a global counter for the image recheck attempts
var thisRetry = 0;

// set the recheck interval and store it in a variable in order to be able to stop it later
var recheckInterval = window.setInterval(recheckImages,interval);

// function to call when image encounters an error
function imageError(e) {
 $(e).attr('data-src',$(e).attr('src'));
 $(e).attr('src','http://placehold.it/200x100/B40000/ffffff?text=404');
}

// function we call at a given iterval
function recheckImages() {
 if(thisRetry < maxRetry) {
  $("[data-src]").each(function( index ) {
   $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-src'));
  });
  thisRetry++;
  console.log("Images rechecked " + thisRetry + " times!");
 } else {
  console.log("Max rechecks reached!");
  clearInterval(recheckInterval);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100?text=OK" onerror="imageError(this)">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100?text=OK" onerror="imageError(this)">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/broken.jpg" onerror="imageError(this)">
```

Comment: This looks like it is working great! Thanks for the help on this. I saw multiple posts regarding the setting of `null` and never thought that would have been the issue

Comment: Glad I could help and I wish I noticed that sooner. As per my last comment to the original question: "the suggestion to include it in order to avoid loops was wrong because it assumed that you are calling your image recheck function from within the onerror handler rather than setting it up externally".

The only way setting this.onerror=null would have NOT been a problem is if you were to set it to something else within the execution of your onerror handler but that would be useless in this case.