# React - setState inside componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I am building a lazyloading component for images. But I have a problem with setting state. I'm getting **Can only update a mounted or mounting component** error, but I am using `setState` inside `componentDidMount`, which should allow me to avoid such errors.

Here's my code:

```
export default class Images extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.element = null;

        this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            height: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.element = findDOMNode(this);

        this.loadImage();
    }

    getDimensions() {
        const w = this.element.offsetWidth;

        let initw = 0;
        let inith = 0;

        let result;

        const img = new Image();
        img.src = this.props.url;

        img.onload = (e) => {
            initw = e.path[0].width;
            inith = e.path[0].height;

            result = (w / initw) * inith;

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    loaded: true,
                    height: `${result}px`
                });
            });
        }
    }

    loadImage() {
        _scrolling.add([this.element], () => {
            if (this.element.classList.contains(_scrolling.classes.coming)) { // the image is visible
                this.getDimensions();
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        const classes = this.state.loaded ? `${this.props.parentClass}__image--loaded` : null;
        const styles = this.state.loaded ? {
            maxHeight: this.state.height, minHeight: this.state.height, overflow: 'hidden'
        } : null;

        return (
            <div className={`${this.props.parentClass}__image ${classes}`} style={styles}>
                {this.state.loaded ?
                    <img
                        className={`${this.props.parentClass}__img`}
                        src={this.props.url}
                        title={this.props.title}
                        alt={this.props.title}
                    />
                    : null
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I belive the problem lies within `img.onload`, but I don't know how to achieve this otherwise. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you attempt to set state on an unmounted component, you’ll get an error like that.There are two solutions:

1. Assure Component isMounted : use `setstate();` after checking that the component is mounted or not.
2. Abort the Request: When the component unmounts, we can just throw away the request so the callback is never invoked. To do this, we’ll take advantage of another React lifecycle hook, `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Hi Jason, 
how can I abort the request in componentWillUnmount, can you post an example?

Comment: I was using https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent for network request, which provided me an abort method. Like this: 
componentWillUnmount: function () {
    this.req.abort()
  }

Comment: I understand, but please remember that this is an image, so using AJAX produced "gibberish" (image source in text format) instead of what I recieve with `onload`.

Comment: Can you do a quick test by checking  if the component is unmounted or not in componentDidMount? does it  produce  error or not?

Comment: I put `console.log` inside `componentWillUnmount` and it runs, so propably yes - this is the issue.

Comment: Cool, Don't forget to put a tick mark if my answer helps :P

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `img.onload` handler is getting called on an unmounted `Images` component instance.

Image loading is asynchronous and takes some time. When it’s finally done and `img.onload` handler gets called, there is no guarantee your component is still mounted.

You have to make use of `componentWillUnmount` and make sure you either:

- Cancel the image loading before component gets unmounted, or
- Keep the track of the component’s mounted state and check if it’s mounted once your handler gets called

More about checking if a component is mounted or not: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

### Solution: Cancel The Image Loading

```
export default class Images extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.element = null;

        this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            height: 0
        };

        this.images = []; // We’ll store references to the Image objects here.
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.element = findDOMNode(this);

        this.loadImage();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.images.forEach(img => img.src = ''); // Cancel the loading of images.
    }

    getDimensions() {
        const w = this.element.offsetWidth;

        let initw = 0;
        let inith = 0;

        let result;

        const img = new Image();
        img.src = this.props.url;

        img.onload = (e) => {
            initw = e.path[0].width;
            inith = e.path[0].height;

            result = (w / initw) * inith;

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    loaded: true,
                    height: `${result}px`
                });
            });
        }

        this.images.push(img); // Store the reference.
    }

    loadImage() {
        _scrolling.add([this.element], () => {
            if (this.element.classList.contains(_scrolling.classes.coming)) { // the image is visible
                this.getDimensions();
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        const classes = this.state.loaded ? `${this.props.parentClass}__image--loaded` : null;
        const styles = this.state.loaded ? {
            maxHeight: this.state.height, minHeight: this.state.height, overflow: 'hidden'
        } : null;

        return (
            <div className={`${this.props.parentClass}__image ${classes}`} style={styles}>
                {this.state.loaded ?
                    <img
                        className={`${this.props.parentClass}__img`}
                        src={this.props.url}
                        title={this.props.title}
                        alt={this.props.title}
                    />
                    : null
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I copied the image cancelling from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278475/594458

Comment: It doesn't work without moving the single image to the other component. Additionally, it produces `Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null` error.

Comment: Ok, I’ve updated the proposed solution. It stores the array of images and cancels them when the component is about to get unmounted. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried the same solution and it also doesn't work. The problem comes when I rerender the parent copmonent (load more items via ajax).

Comment: Are you sure that the `setState` call in `onload` handler is the one raising the warning? Can you create a jsfiddle or codepen example?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, console traces it back to my js file and the line with `onload`. I can't create a fiddle for this, it's too complex.