# How can I cancel image decoding in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, webassembly, imagedecoder

To transform binary image data (e.g. from a file input) into a canvas image source, [createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap) or [Image.decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) can be used.

Is there a cancellable alternative to these methods?

I want to render images from a multiple file `input` to a `canvas` element, one at a time. My current approach causes severe delays, if additional decode operations are started while the previous ones still run (I am only interested in the result of the most recent one).

I found out that `Image.decode` can be cancelled in some browsers, by reassinging the image `src`. However, this does not work universally (e.g. not in Firefox).

I am open to use third party libraries, as long as they are performant (WebAssembly) and free and if they at least support the most basic image formats like JPEG and PNG.

## Edit

To clarify things, I created a Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Tims777/pen/bGxvgBQ

Just select a bunch (100+) of large (~20MP) JPEGs and hold down the up button for a while to torture your CPU.

Comment: _"My current approach causes severe delays"_ - please post your current actual code, and please explain exactly what you mean by "severe delays" - do you mean the browser's UI thread is blocked - or just that it takes a long time (but is otherwise non-blocking)?

Comment: The code is part of a larger application so I did not include an exemple yet. I will try and put together a minimal example.

Comment: By `Image.decode`, do you mean `HTMLImageElement.decode`? If so, then because that's a `Promise`-returning function it means that you can always _ignore_ the Promise's result when cancelled or after a timeout, even if the `Promise`-returning function doesn't support cancelling.

Comment: I added an example now. As you can see, ignoring the promise result is not enough, because it will leave the decode operation running in the background.

Comment: As a workaround, you could prevent the user from having more than N-many concurrent `decode` operations, say, 3 or 4, that way having 20 images wouldn't make the computer melt - though I agree it's not exactly ideal.

Comment: BTW, people report that Firefox _does_ support cancelling an image-load operation, but the catch is you have to reset `.src` to a valid image URI, not an empty-string (or has it changed in recent Firefox builds?). [Another suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48639311/159145) is to load the image in a WebWorker, and to kill the worker on-abort - though I don't know how well that would work in-practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dai I can now answer my own question:

Using a WebWorker makes for a pretty straightforward solution, since the worker can be cancelled right in the middle of execution whenever the need arises.

The `worker.js` itself can be as simple as this:

```
onmessage = function(event) {
    createImageBitmap(event.data).then(image => postMessage(image));
}
```

And here is my reworked `update` function:

```
function update() {
    abortController?.abort();
    abortController = new AbortController();

    if (indexInput.valueAsNumber > fileInput.files.length) return;
    const file = fileInput.files[indexInput.valueAsNumber];
    const signal = abortController.signal;

    const worker = new Worker("worker.js");
    worker.onmessage = (message) => ctx1.drawImage(message.data, 0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
    worker.postMessage(file);
    signal.onabort = () => worker.terminate();
}
```

Comment: Btw your code doesnt handle the case when `fileInput.files.length === 0` (which is when the user clicks Browse and removes the file selection)

Comment: Also I’m curious if you can cache the worker instance - and I’m unsure if it’s always safe to call `postMessage` before wiring-up the `message` event-handler.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to restart a worker instance, once it has been terminated - so there is probably no way around recreating the worker every time.
Regarding your other two points, I tried updating my answer accordingly to address those.