# Preloading images through iframes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, caching, iframe

Working on a script that is supposed to preload images by putting them into iframes. When a button is clicked, it will preload even more images and stop previous iframes from loading (no longer needed).
I am receiving two errors though that I cannot figure out:

1. Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
   image/jpeg
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of
   undefined

The latter error means my script is not fully working so my question is : what's wrong with my code?
Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ke3/5/)

```
 function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        image_iframe[this] = $('<iframe />').appendTo('body')[0];
        image_iframe[this].onload = function() {
            console.log('Image Cached!');
            this.remove();
        };
        image_iframe[this].src = image_url[this];
    });
}

var image_iframe = [];
var image_url = []; 

image_url[1] = '/image.jpg';
image_url[2] = '/another-image.jpg';
image_url[...] = 'etc';

preload([2, 3]);
var current_url = 1;

function nextImage() {
    if( current_url <= 50) {
        current_url = current_url + 1;
        preload([current_url + 1, current_url + 2]);
        for (var z=1;z<current_url;z++) {
            image_iframe[z].contentWindow.stop();
            image_iframe[z].execCommand("Stop", false);
        }
    } else {
        window.location.replace("/");
    }
}

$('#remove').click(function(){ 
    nextImage();
});
```

The reason I'm using iframes is because I need a way to stop specific images from loading. 
[Cancel single image request in html5 browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926215/cancel-single-image-request-in-html5-browsers)

**EDIT:** I think the problem is in how I define `image_iframe[]` 
**EDIT2:** Gosh forgot that I started my preload at `2`, which means that my loop (which starts at 1) gives an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg

Fixed itself

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined

I started with array 2 in the preload but looped from 1