# How to abort image loading

Tags: javascript, image, browser

I'm trying to reduce the amount of consumed traffic. That's why I have to cancel loading of unnecessary images. As I'm trying to cancel loading of few images, not all, so I can't use method

```js
window.stop();
```

I was trying to replace SRC of unnecessary images to empty string value

```js
img.src = '';
```

But it works just in Chrome and Opera and still trying to load at least part of the image (few kb of the whole image size). This is not a solution, but still it helps to reduce the amount of consumed traffic. But this solution is not good for Firefox and Safari. Also I was trying to change

```js
img.src = '1px.png';
```

with a small size (1kb or less) but it is still not a solution.

Also I tried to remove element from HTML.

```js
img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
```

This code helps just to remove elements from HTML but images are continue loading.

Is there any effective solution that works in all browsers and completely canceled the image loading?

Comment: [All about image lazy-loading](https://www.google.com/search?q=image+lazy+loading&rlz=1C5CHFA_enBD695BD695&oq=image+laz&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l3j0.2349j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I know about lazy loading a lot. But it's not a solution. The question was in how can I cancel/abort image loading.

Comment: Then don't load images at all and load if needed (lazy-loading), isn't it same?

Comment: Nope it's not the same. If I have a static html with many images and I can't change it at all lazyloading is not a solution. I'll repeat that I'm looking for how can I cancel/abort image loading. That's my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel single image request in html5 browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926215/cancel-single-image-request-in-html5-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Firefox network throttling problem when you decrease the speed of your network. You must check it with real slow network.

You can use
`img.src ='';`
in Firefox too.

When you speed down network with throttling, Firefox will download the image with real speed but show download progress with low speed and when you want to cancel it in the middle of download, you can't do it because image was loaded before.

Comment: Do you know if this fires an onError or some kind of event?

Answer (score -1):

I noticed you haven't tried the following yet:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $("img").removeAttr("src"); 
});
```

Or you could try (and change the url to your image url):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img[src*="image.com/img.png"]';) 
});
```

**A new idea** (that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929662/how-do-i-abort-image-img-load-requests-without-using-window-stop)):

1) initiate an AJAX request for the image, if it succeeds, the image goes to the browser cache, and once you set the 'src' attribute, the image is shown from the cache

2) you can abort the XHR

I wrote a tiny server with express emulating the huge image download (it actually just waits 20 seconds, then returns an image). Then I have this in my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            img {
                width: 469px;
                height: 428px;
                background-color: #CCC;
                border: 1px solid #999;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img data-src="./img" src="" />
        <br />
        <a id="cancel" href="javascript:void(0)">CANCEL</a>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var xhr, img = $('img'), src = img.data('src');

                xhr = $.ajax(src, {
                    success: function (data) { img.attr('src', src) }
                });

                $('#cancel').click(function (){
                    xhr.abort();
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body> </html>
```

Comment: It's not a solution, images are still loading

Comment: @zhuravlyov I have added a possible third solution that should work :)

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is not a solution too :( because we have a static HTML with src values in it :(