# How to stop Ajax image load calling a new function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

I'm doing something like this ->

```
$("<img>").attr("src", "path/to/image.jpg").load(function(){
    $("#thediv").append(this);
});
```

so i can append the new image when the image is completely loaded

I have a timer to call this function with new parameters every 6 seconds.... but I want to call a function to load a new set of images but I have this old set running in background ( asynchronous ) and i need to stop that load so the image won't append beacuse i don't want that image  and I'm trying to load a whole new different set of images... I was thinking on something like :

```
function loadNewSet(){
   window.stop(); // i don't quite know if this exist or works but 
                 //should stop all ajax request taking place at that time
   loadImages(); // call some function to load the new set
}
```

/**/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/

To be more specific:

I have a div called `thediv` where I'll  be placing my images

then I have set of images or an array

```
set1 = ['img1','img2','img3']
```

and

```
set2 = ['img4','img5','img6']
```

and i have `thetimer` set on the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    thetimer=setTimeout("nextSlide()",6000);
});
```

then i have `nextSlide()`

```
function nextSlide(){
     //this is where i load the next image on the active set (set 1 or set 2)
    img.load(function(){
       thetimer=setTimeout("nextSlide()",6000); // and then i set the timer again
    });
}
```

but when the `nextSlide()` function is called it'd be like idle while the new image is loading and after it loads it'd the things it's supposed to do on `load()` but what it while loading i call this function `loadNewSet()`

```
function loadNewSet(set){
    clearTimeout(thetimer);
    //this is wheere i want to stop any image loading called by any other function
    stopAllImagesLoading();//example
    //then change activeset
    activeSet=set; // set1 or set2
    nextSlide();
}
```

Don't quite know if I'm doing this the right way and may be I can't put down the procces here the way I'm doing it.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the anwser here:
[Javascript: Cancel/Stop Image Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930237/javascript-cancel-stop-image-requests/1468452#1468452)

```
    if(window.stop !== undefined)
    {
         window.stop();
    }
    else if(document.execCommand !== undefined)
    {
         document.execCommand("Stop", false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn up "worker processes" by using setTimeout.

```
var proc;
somefunc();

function somefunc() {
    //do stuff
    proc = setTimeout(somefunc, 6000);
}

//...

clearTimeout(proc); //Cancel the looping somefunc from executing.
```

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of appending, you do something like....

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <img id="myImg" style="display: none">
</div>
```

...

```
function loadImg(url){
    $("#myImg").attr("src", url).load(function(){
        if(url == $(this).attr(url)){
            // The currently requested image has loaded.  Show it.
            $(this).show();
        }
        else{
            // Finished loading an image that we don't need anymore.  Do nothing.
        }
    });
}
```

So if you called:

```
loadImg("a.jpg");
loadImg("b.jpg");
```

a.jpg might or might not finish first, but it doesn't matter because once a.jpg finishes, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a global variable to turn on or off the timer. For instance (pseudo-code only):

```
var gKeepRunning = true;   //KEY TO ANSWER HERE

myRepeatingImageLoader();   //this is the method that will repeat

function myRepeatingImageLoader(){
  $("<img>").attr("src", "path/to/image.jpg").load(function(){
    $("#thediv").append(this);
  });

  if( gKeepRunning == true )   //KEY TO ANSWER HERE - WILL STOP WHEN SET TO FALSE
    var junk = setTimeout('myRepeatingImageLoader();', 6000);   //Repeat again
}

function loadNewSet(){
  gKeepRunning == false;   //KEY TO ANSWER HERE
  loadImages();
}
```