# How to load an other image, if the current image loads slow?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a HTML5 canvas game, and I want to load a high resolution image as background. This image is 10MB, so if the image loads slow, then I want to load a smaller image instead.

```
var myimg = new Image();
myimg.onload = function() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  alert('high resolution image loaded');
};
mximg.src = 'path/to/highres.png';

var t = setTimeout(function(){
  //cancel loading somehow ?
  myimg.onload = function() {
    alert('low resolution image loaded');
  };
  myimg.src = 'path/to/low_res.png';
},5000);
```

should I cancel somehow the loading, or it's cancelled if I edit the src attribute?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930237/javascript-cancel-stop-image-requests

Comment: I can't use window.stop, because I load more objects async.

Comment: bad news~ I'll find another one~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative "solution" would be to load the low-res image first. Only if it loaded quickly enough you start to load the high-res version to replace it.

There are three possible benefits as I see it:

1. You avoid having to worry about cancelling the load :-)
2. You avoid loading unnecessary data (the partially downloaded high-res image) when the user is on low bandwidth, but instead load unnecessary data (the complete low-res image) when the user is on high bandwidth (in which case it doesn't matter that much anyway).
3. While you load the high-res image, you have the option to show the low-res image as a placeholder (requires that you load the low-res and high-res images into two separarate DOM Image objects and swap out the low-res with the high-res).

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the loading of images, however it is possible to cancel an ordinary AJAX request ([see this solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)). Usually images aren't loaded via AJAX for good reasons, but you can work around this by sending the image as a base64 encoded string. So you let PHP read the image and convert it to base64. This string can be sent to JS via AJAX and "directly" drawn to your canvas ([solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas)).

I really don't know if this is the best way to do this... Anyways, see if this works for you:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="background" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript:** (using jQuery)

```
function drawBackgroundImage(src) {
    var image = $("<img/>").load(function(){
        $("canvas#background")[0].getContext("2d").drawImage(image[0], 0, 0);
    }).attr("src", src);
}
function loadImage(highres, lowres) {
    var t;
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_image.php",
        data: "image=" + highres,
        success: function(imgbinary){
            if (imgbinary != "") {
                clearTimeout(t);
                drawBackgroundImage(imgbinary);
            }
        }
    });
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        xhr.abort();
        drawBackgroundImage(lowres);
    }, 5000);
}

loadImage("path/to/highres.png", "path/to/low_res.png");
```

**PHP:** (load_image.php)

(This uses part of a [function from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.base64-encode.php#107705).)

```
<?php
    $result = "";
    @ob_start();
    if (isset($_POST["image"])) {
        $filename = $_POST["image"];
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            $filetype = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
            $result = "data:image/".$filetype.";base64,".base64_encode($imgbinary);
        }
    }
    @ob_end_clean();
    echo $result;
?>
```