# Stop loading a image on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JS software that will load a lot of small images. 
But a lot of these images stop being necessary but the browser keeps loading them instead of the new images I added later.

Long story made short: I have a `Image` that is still loading, can I cancel the image loading?

Ps1: I saw there are lot of question on Stackoverflow about it, but these questions refers to a `<img>` that didnt start loading yet, my Image is already loading.

Ps2: If there is no standard way to do this, working with Firefox and Google Chrome is enough...

Comment: This sounds similar...stopping images in the middle of a request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930237/javascript-cancel-stop-image-requests?rq=1

Comment: And see `window.stop()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.stop. "...it will stop the loading of large images, new windows, and other objects whose loading is deferred."

Comment: @TimMedora I wasnt willing to stop every image. It would be better if I could select which image to stop loading.