# Postponing and manual control of <img> loading when images will be eventually hidden via media queries

Tags: html, css, webkit, media-queries

I have a web page which uses several `<img>` elements which are not visible by default.

- Images are used in a carousel
- Some images are set hidden using `display: none` via mobile.css and CSS media queries

How do browsers, especially mobile browsers, queue image loading? Is it possible to exert fine-tuned control over images, so that

- Images are not loaded until they become visible
- Image loading is aborted by mobile.css or accomppaning Javascript if mobile media queries kick in
- What is the difference between CSS background images and `<img>` element images behavior-wise (if any)

What strategies do mobile browsers (WebKit) use in this kind of situation?

As an example site I can use open sourced site http://fi.pycon.org/2012/ It has a logo element created with HTML and CSS

https://github.com/python-finland/fi.pycon.org/blob/master/2012/index.html#L85

And this element is visible by default (desktop)

https://github.com/python-finland/fi.pycon.org/blob/master/media/2012/css/theme.css#L99

But eventually hidden for mobile browsers via mobile.css and media queries:

https://github.com/python-finland/fi.pycon.org/blob/master/media/2012/css/moobile.css#L20

- Are mobile browsers optimized so that the logo image file is not loaded?
- Would the case be different if `<img>` element were used for the logo?
- Does it matter if overriding CSS rules are in a different CSS file (and  media query)

Note: It is out of the scope of this question how media queries should be handled and I am not interested in answers which tell to build the basic CSS and media queries in a different manner. I am well aware of these solutions.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there are no viable standardized options for preventing images in <img> tags from loading with straight-up HTML+CSS. This is one of the reasons the [W3C Responsive Images working group](http://www.w3.org/community/respimg/common-questions-and-concerns/) was formed:

> ...no proposed CSS-based solution accounts for one of the fundimental [sic] issues that we’re looking to avoid: downloading multiple assets at larger screen widths, as requests can be made before the swapping logic is applied.

This is not to say that a JavaScript-based interim solution cannot work, only that pure HTML+CSS -based solution will not work. So, to answer your questions:

> #### 1. Are mobile browsers optimized so that the logo image file is not loaded?

No. [hidden elements](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/11/do-hidden-elements-load-background-images/) [will load](http://www.webdesignshock.com/responsive-design-problems/) their background images.

> #### 2. Would the case be different if  element were used for the logo?

No. Images will very likely begin loading pre-emptively [before CSS is applied](http://www.w3.org/community/respimg/common-questions-and-concerns/).

> #### 3. Does it matter if overriding CSS rules are in a different CSS file (and media query)

No. This will likely cause even more delay for the swapping logic mentioned in answer #2 to apply, thus increasing the possibility that images have already started loading.

Comment: If this is the sad state of the things I will result to Javascript trickery to work around these problems.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930237/javascript-cancel-stop-image-requests

Comment: Well here's a good summary of all the dirtiness you can end up having... http://24ways.org/2011/adaptive-images-for-responsive-designs-again