# AngularJS wrong scope value

Tags: angularjs

I have a html5-tag using the scope to set the src:

```
<video style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%" controls>
    <source src="/files/{{item.path}}" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

If I load this template I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8070/files/%7B%7Bitem.path%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Btw. this is not the correct value of item.path. If I set the path manually it works:

```
<source src="/files/./5315dfea66469e28166e85c6/5315dfea66469e28166e85c6_20143414248143.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: try to use `ng-src` instead... the problem is the video is trying to get the url before angular app is bootstrapped

Comment: as drex said, it's another angular-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue with Angular:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352

ng-src is appropriate here. however, it is confirmed to not work in all browsers and is suspected to be a bug in the browser rather than with Angular.

There is a possible workaround here: [HTML5 video element request stay pending forever (on chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137381/html5-video-element-request-stay-pending-forever-on-chrome)

Comment: Oh, didn't found that issue by myself. I always come to a point where angularjs isn't fun anymore. Getting there now :(