# HTML5 video strange rendering error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I'm trying to create something where when a user clicks on a miniature version of a HTML5 video, a popup comes up which shows an enlarged version of the video (kind of like Instagram) .

However, there seems to be a strange error only in Chrome, where after I exit out of the popup and reopen it repeatedly by clicking on the blanket (about 3-5 times), the enlarged video fails to render properly in the popup (it shows up as a miniature black screen that wont play).

All other videos will also fail to enlarge properly if I click on them after that point. This occurs when I repeatedly click on a video of 3.6MB but it doesn't seem to occur when I click on a small video of 61KB so I'm not sure if the size of the file has anything to do with it.

Even stranger, when a video fails to render after repeatedly opening and closing the popups, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, which brings up the inspector renders the video properly. Adding a click event to the enlarged video with only alert() also renders it properly.

The mp4 file definitely plays properly prior to this happening.

Just noticed something -- the more I open and close the popups, the longer it takes Chrome to refresh the page, and it says either "Processing Request" or "Waiting for available socket" at the bottom left corner.

**New Update** - It seems the issue is related to sockets. I'm not really familiar with the subject, but Chrome has "6 sockets max per group". Each time I fetch the `src` from the smaller thumbnail video, and insert it into the larger video, through this code:

```
var media_to_append=...;
```

It creates a new socket. This occurs for a 3.6M video and not a 61K video or images. When I reach the limit of 6 sockets for localhost, the expanded video fails to render. Strangely, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> removes 2 active sockets, and `alert();` removes 4, allowing me to create more sockets through every video click.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue- by not creating sockets?

```html
<div id='video_container' style='height:150px; width:150px; background:black;'>
<video style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;">
     <source src='some_file.mp4' type="video/mp4"></source>
</video></div>
```

```js
$("#video_container").click(function(){
    var src=$("#video_container").find("video").find("source").attr("src");
    var blanket=$("<div class='blanket' id='view_media_blanket' onclick='$(\"#view_media_popup\").remove(); $(this).remove();' style='z-index:15; background:#111; opacity:0.65; width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;'></div>");
    $(document.body).append(blanket);
    var popup_height=600;
    var popup=$("<div id='view_media_popup' style='text-align:center; z-index:15; width:1000px; height:"+popup_height+"px; position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; margin-left:-500px; margin-top:-300px;  background:white;'></div>");
    $(document.body).append(popup); 

    var media_to_append=$('<video class="expanded_media" data-type="video" style=" position:absolute; left:0px; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; margin:auto; cursor:pointer; max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" controls ><source  src="'+src+'"  type="video/mp4"></source></video>');

    $(media_to_append).click(function(e) {///if the rendering of the video fails, clicking on it with an alert(); or pressing CTRL SHIFT i renders it properly.
        alert();
    });

    popup.append(media_to_append);
});
```

Comment: Looks like you found a Chrome bug. Maybe try it in Canari to see if it's fixed in a more recent build.

Comment: each time I create an expanded HTML video, Chrome is creating an active socket. When the number of sockets reaches 6, the HTML video rendering fails

Comment: If your page only contains the video, you can wrap it in an invisible div and show it when you click the thumbnail.

Comment: My problem is that each HTML <video> tag seems to PERMANENTLY create a socket, which remains even after the <video> tag is removed by Jquery. Therefore,a user can only open a popup and view the video until the socket number has reached the maximum.

Comment: Did you try creating your element using javascript's `document.createElement()`?

Comment: What if you just hide the video tag and recycle it later with a new `src` value? That way you make sure it doesn't reach the limit of 6 sockets, even tho video tags loading files and not sockets shouldn't create sockets, obviously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 video element request stay pending forever (on chrome)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137381/html5-video-element-request-stay-pending-forever-on-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for the help.

I found out that this is a bug in Chrome.

[HTML5 video element request stay pending forever (on chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137381/html5-video-element-request-stay-pending-forever-on-chrome)

explains how to fix the problem. It seems that each  attribute has to be explicity removed and the src attr of the video must be set to false.

```
    if($('.expanded_source').length>0 && isChrome){ 
            $('.expanded_media').prop('src', false);
            $('.expanded_source').remove(); 
        }
        $('.expanded_media').remove();
        $("#view_media_popup").remove(); 
        $(blanket).remove();
```

This apparently closes the socket.

The link also has solutions to how to append multiple HTML5 videos on a page without crashing