# chrome html5 video requests stay pending while video is playing

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video, asp.net-web-api2

I'm currently working on a eLearning website where I use html5 video tag to show video tutorials to my users. I'm using the video streaming technique explained here:
https://getpocket.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstudentguru.gr%2Fb%2Feloy%2Farchive%2F2015%2F07%2F13%2Fvideo-streaming-for-mobile-clients-via-asp-net-web-api-2-tutorial.

After I implemented this solution everything works fine, but after a while I realized while video is playing using html5 video tag in chrome, other requests that are sent to the same server, stays pending for a long time. I don't have this issue on other browsers link Firefox. This is because of a specific bug in chrome (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/455). This is a major problem for me because while users are watching videos on my website, I use ajax to save their progress and this issue prevents that. Do you know any workaround to fix this issue? I have used solutions in [HTML5 video element request stay pending forever (on chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137381/html5-video-element-request-stay-pending-forever-on-chrome) and none of them solved my problem.

Thanks in advanced.

[image]