# HTML5 video element request stay pending forever (on chrome in mobile) when toggle over front-rare camera

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video.js, mediaelement.js

I'm developing an app where users can capture photo using a front/rare camera. it working perfectly but when toggle over camera front/rare **var playPromise = videoStream.play()** is gone in pending state. some times promise get resolve, the camera is working sometimes not.

> this issue occurs only in chrome browser not in mozila and firefox

> ```
>        try {
>             stopWebCam(); // stop media stream when toggle over camera
>             stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
>             /* use the stream */
>             let videoStream = document.getElementById('captureCandidateId');
>             videoStream.srcObject = stream;
>
>                 // videoStream.play();
>                 var playPromise = videoStream.play();
>
>                 if (playPromise !== undefined) {
>                   playPromise.then(_ => {
>                     // Automatic playback started!
>                     // Show playing UI.
>                                  
>                   })
>                   .catch(error => {
>                     // Auto-play was prevented
>                     // Show paused UI.
>                   });
>                 }
>
>                                 };
>         } catch(err) {
>             /* handle the error */
>             
>             console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
>         }
> ```

> ```
>     let stopWebCam = function (pictureType) {
>
>     setTimeout(()=>{
>         let videoStream = document.getElementById('captureCandidateId');
>         const stream = videoStream.srcObject;
>         if (stream && stream.getTracks) {
>             const tracks = stream.getTracks();
>             tracks.forEach(function(track) {
>                 track.stop();
>             });
>         }
>         videoStream.srcObject = null;
>       }, 0)
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I drafted a piece of code for you, this is much more simple and smaller approach than what you are trying to do. I am just taking the stream from the video element and drawing it to canvas. Image can be downloaded by right clicking.
NOTE: Example does not work in StackOverflow

```html
<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
<button id="capture">Capture</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
<script>
  const player = document.getElementById('player');
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');

  const constraints = {
    video: true,
  };

  captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
    context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  });

  // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
      player.srcObject = stream;
    });
</script>
```

If you want, you can also make some edits according to your needs, like:

1. Choose which camera to use
2. Hide the video stream
3. Add a easier method to download the photo on your device
4. You can also add a functionality to upload the photo straight to the server if you have one

Comment: this issue occcurs in chrome browser only

Answer (score -1):

check if the video resolution is exceed 4k(3840x2160). if true, try downscale.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).