# Forcing an HTTP request to fail in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, firefox, httprequest

Is it possible to make an http request that has been sent to a server by the browser fail without having to alter the javascript?

I have a POST request that my website is sending to the server and we are trying to test how our code reacts when the request fails (e.g. an HTTP 500 response). Unfortunately, the environment that I need to test it in has uglified and compressed javascript, so inserting a breakpoint or altering the javascript isn't an option. Is there a way for us to utilize any browser to simulate a failed request?

The request takes a long time to complete, so using the browser's console to run a javascript command is a possibility.

I have tried [using window.stop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930237/javascript-cancel-stop-image-requests), however, this does not work since I need to failure code to execute.

I am aware of the option of setting up a proxy server, but would like to avoid this is possible.

Comment: Why don't you simply set a HTTP 500 in the test server when the request comes in?

Comment: I don't have access to alter the server code.

Comment: Have you tried chrome extensions like `Tamper Chrome`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In Chrome (just checked v63), you can actually block a specific URL (or even a whole domain) from the Network tab. You only need to right-click on the entry and select `Block request URL` (or `Block request domain`.)

Comment: Thanks, great answer

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution is to modify the XMLHttpRequest objects that will be used by the browser. Running this code in a javascript console will cause all future AJAX calls on the page to be redirected to a different URL (which will probably give a 404 error):

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype._old_open =
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype._old_open || XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
  return XMLHttpRequest.prototype._old_open.call(
    this, method, 'TEST-'+url, async, user, pass);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't overlook the simplest solution: disconnect your computer from the Internet, and then trigger the AJAX call.

Comment: You can also do that choosing **Offline** checkbox in Chrome's **Network** in **Tools > Developer Tools**.

Comment: That does not work when you have several requests going on at the same time and you want to block only one of them...

Answer (score 4):

To block a specific URL and make an API call failure, you just need to follow below steps:

1. Go to Network tab in your browser.
2. Find that API call which needs to fail(as per your requirement).
3. Right click on that API call and
   [image]
4. Click on 'Block Request URL', you can unblock as well in same manner as the option will turn into 'Unblock'
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's dev tools have an option to "beautify" (i.e. re-indent) minified JavaScript (press the "{}" button at the bottom left). This can be combined with the "XHR breakpoint" option to break when the request is made. XHR breakpoints don't support modifying the response though AFAIK, but you should be able to find a way to do it via code.

Answer (score -6):

Just type at the brower a changed URL, e.g. the well formed URL e.g. http://thedomain.com/welcome/  by another placing "XX": http://thedomain.com/welcomeXX/ , that will cause a 404 error (not found)